# SQL Select Query : Change column name

Tags: sql

I have the following simple select statement:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE        
(TABLE_NAME = 'Raw_TESTB') AND (ORDINAL_POSITION >= '2') OR
(TABLE_NAME = 'Raw_TESTC') AND (ORDINAL_POSITION >= '5') AND 
(COLUMN_NAME = '1hr_avg' OR
COLUMN_NAME = 'MA_O7_1hr' OR
COLUMN_NAME = 'Am_te_avg' OR
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME DESC
```

QUESTION: How can i change the result 'MA_O7_1hr' in COLUMN_NAME = 'MA_O7_1hr' into MA_09_4hr?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you wanted to change a column name. If that's the case, use `ALTER TABLE` statement for the database you are using. Also, I recommend putting parenthesis around filters that use AND e.g. `((table_name = 'a' and ordinal_position > 1) OR (table_name = 'b' and ordinal_position > 4)) AND column_name in ('a', 'b', 'c')`. In your case, I'd also remove the `top 100 percent` clause

Comment: So in column_name in ('a', 'b', 'c') ,how i can change 'c' into 'test'?

Comment: Just type column_name in ('a', 'b', 'test'). That means, you are filtering your results to only those records that have column_name of either 'a', 'b' or 'test' in addition to any other filters you may have applied.

Comment: I dont have column 'test' but i want convert column 'c' name into 'test' name..

Comment: If you want a column in a table renamed, use ALTER TABLE statement. Is that what you want? If you give some examples of what you see and what you want, it might become a little easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

Use Alias

```
SELECT column_name AS alias_name
FROM table_name;
```